# tinymce readonly mode event not firing

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg

I have a requirement where i need to display side by side a source code editor and a wysiwyg editor such as tinymce . The idea is that the user should click on any element inside the wysiwg editor and the corresponding element should highlight in the source code editor.

So far i have been able to get the selected node in tinymce by using the onnodechange event

```
setup: function(ed) {
            ed.on('NodeChange', function(e){
                console.log(e.element);
            });
        }
```

but, the event doesn't fire when the editor is in readonly mode. Do you know why this is happening or can you suggest me a way to overcome this issue ?

Answer (score 4):

I have found a workaround by adding the following inside setup callback

```
//prevent user to edit content inside tinymce
    ed.on('PostRender', function(e){
        ed.getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
    });

    ed.on('KeyPress', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

It's not perfect, but at least, it does the trick ;)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, but we needed to intercept the click event, not "NodeChange".

I resolved by adding the event handler directly on the body element of the tinymce iframe and using the event target.

```
bodyEl.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log('Hello ', e.target);
}, false)
```

If you need to detect selection change, you could use the 'select' event.